# Creating JTree using parsed XML document

Tags: java, swing

i want to create a JTree resembling XML dom in java.. below is the XML form...

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <style></style>
    <body></body>
  </head> 
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <style></style>
    <body></body>
  </head>
</html>
```

i want to create this tree structure....

Comment: Couldn't find anything below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it easily by parsing the XML and creating a `DefaultMutableTreeNode` for each XML element. Tree nodes have parents and children just like XML elements so the mapping is easy.

If you set the Element as the user object in `DefaultMutableTreeNode` you will probably want to provide a custom `TreeCellRenderer`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a full example here: http://www.cafeconleche.org/books/xmljava/chapters/ch06s05.html